# How to add dynamic column to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables 1st table contains following columns,

```
 id code    Name
 1  c1  chk1
 2  c2  chk2
 3  c3  chk3
```

2nd table contains following columns,

```
id,Name,Chk1,chk2,Chk3
```

i have to add the column 'Chk4' into table2 if table1 is updated with value '4,'c4','ch4' dynamically.How to write procedure to perform this?

i've tried the following procedure but its not working fine.

```
         create proc Add_Check
          as 
          begin
          declare @Column varchar(50)
          declare @query varchar(255)
          declare @query1 varchar(255)
          set @Column= (select top 1 QUOTENAME(Name)
            from table1 where id=(Select MAX id) from table1))
          if exists(select 1 from table1
         where Name=@Column) 
         begin
         set @query = 'alter table table2 add ' + @Column + ' Varchar (50)'
         set @query1 = 'alter table table2 add ' + @Column + '_CompletedDate Varchar (50)'
         exec(@query)
         end
         end
```

Comment: check my answer now. i update my answer after update your procedure script.

Comment: It is not working is hardly enough. Please tell us what is happening, when you execute the SP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this query as procedure.

```
CREATE PROC ADD_CHECK
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @COLUMN VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @QUERY1 VARCHAR(255)

    SET @COLUMN= (SELECT TOP 1 NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID=(SELECT MAX (ID)     FROM TABLE1))

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME=@COLUMN) 
    BEGIN
        SET @QUERY = 'ALTER TABLE TABLE2 ADD ' + @COLUMN + ' VARCHAR (50)'
        SET @QUERY1 = 'ALTER TABLE TABLE2 ADD ' + @COLUMN + '_COMPLETEDDATE VARCHAR     (50)'
        EXEC(@QUERY)
    END
END
```

Comment: like my answer if you satisfied withmy answer

Comment: Its getting execute but the new column not getting added

Comment: you use QUOTENAME() function that why it's create problm. remove QUOTENAME() than you get successfully result

Comment: i have declared another variable and added '_COMPLETEDDATE' string in it.its working fine now.Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <procedurename>
AS 
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @COLUMN varchar(10), @SQL Varchar(100);
    SELECT @COLUMN = Name FROM Table1 
    WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table1)
                IF NOT EXISTS(
                              SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
                              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                              WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table2' 
                              AND COLUMN_NAME = @COLUMN
                             )
                 BEGIN
                   SELECT @SQL = 
                          'ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD '
                           +@COLUMN+' varchar(10),'
                           +@COLUMN+'_CompletedDate varchar(50)'
                   EXECUTE (@SQL)
                 END
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Triggers as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AddDynamicColumn_to_table2  
ON Table1  
AFTER INSERT  
AS  
Exec ('ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD ' + (select name from inserted) + ' Varchar(10)')  
GO
```

Comment: it's about create procedure than why use to trigger.